# Maximum number of files you can put in the /assets folder?

Tags: android

Does anyone know the max number of files that can be distributed within the /assets folder? Each of my files is extremely small, but I wonder if there was a limit to the actual # of files that can be placed in there (due to fat32 limitations etc)

Thanks

Comment: If the files are so small and there are so many, maybe you should consider using a sqlite database.

Comment: How many files are you considering?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a limit on the number of files in /assets, it is very large. There is a limit to the number of assets you can have of each type of resource (drawable, layout, string, array, etc.)—something like 2<sup>16</sup> or so. Otherwise I'd recommend putting your files in res/raw.

While you can perhaps put a large number of files into /assets, I would wonder about the access time. Bear in mind that assets can be arranged hierarchically, which might speed up access. (Disclaimer: this entire paragraph is pure speculation.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, your app is distributed in a zip like archive with a size limit of 4GB. Zip does not have a limit per directory, but having 32 bit pointers (at least the official zip, there is a zip64 version) modern zip implementations should allow you up to one million files per archive... in theory, in praxis this would use up the 4GB just for the file pointers alread ;)